# Main 100 amp breaker reads 2 different volts

Tags: circuit-breaker

What if on your main 100 amp breaker one side reads 123v and other side reads 117v? Does that mean my main is bad?

Answer (score 1):

That’s not a big deal. There is probably a imbalance in the load on each line; at that small difference, I probably would not even try to rebalance.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things that could be going on here...

That small variation is within what's normal for household voltage (+/- 10% is fine), so most likely it's nothing to worry about -- you (or your neighbor on the same transformer) just have higher draw on one leg than the other, and that's pulling the voltage down slightly.  If the voltage of each leg doesn't go outside of the +/- 10% range, I wouldn't worry about it.

The other possibility is that your neutral wire has come loose, either in your panel or more likely at the pole.  This is a dangerous situation because, while your two legs will still add up to 240, the value of each relative to neutral can vary wildly (0 & 240, 200 & 40, etc).  If this is what's happening, you'll see different values than what you measured previously as you turn various loads on and off.  If that happens, call the power company and tell them you have a "lost neutral".

Comment: A lost neutral would likely be much more dramatic than a few volts' difference between the legs...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, true, if it's in active use and the panel isn't exceptionally well balanced, I agree.  I only mentioned the possibility in case they either turned off most breakers before taking the reading, or their 240V loads are much larger than their 120V loads (such as a newer house with an on-demand electric water heater, and LED lighting, and not much else).

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Depends on the loads, if the house is very lightly loaded or well balanced, and the earth is conducting well, I could see it.   OP could throw some big loads on one leg and see if it moves...

Comment: Congrats OP!  You got two of the big three here to contribute!  WOW.  Moderator: yeah, I know this is a useless comment. Just had to say it!  Delete if needed. If not I'll do it later!  LOL